# how to render multiple components that has multiple props with the same route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

***here i have one Route that i want it to render two components and each component has its own props, but it's not working!! it renders nothing***

```
        <Route path='/products' components={{top:() =>
    <FilterBar sortProducts={this.sortProducts} sort={this.state.sort} 
        count={this.state.prods.length} SearchChange={this.onSearchChange} />,
           main:()=> <Products addToCart={this.addToCart}  prods={filterdProducts} />
    }}/>
      
      
  **one component is a filter bar and the other is products list so i need to render them both at the same route please help**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is you can put your two components inside Route .

```
<Route path="/path">
 <Component1 />
 <Component2 />
</ Route>
```

and you can pass different props.

Comment: Adil Zamal i can't tell you how stupid i feel lol, it worked thank you very much